# How to avoid Sharepoint Hosted app from generating unique ID in the URL

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am trying to create a SharePoint Hosted app with the ADFS2.0 . What is happening is a unique id is generated on every deployment of the solution. I have to manually register with the new url in the ADFS as the 2.0 doesn't support the wildcard entry. Is there any way to avoid the auto ID generation from the solution.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

What you say is the normal behaviour. Whenever a SharePoint-hosted Add-in is deployed, it will get a new unique app instance ID.

To prevent the app ID from changing, you need to deploy the Add-in to the App Catalog in your farm, and then follow the update process described in [this official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn265910.aspx). Updating the Add-in instead of deploying it with every single change ensures that your Add-in keeps the same ID (same URL as well) while its contents and business logic change.

Comment: There is somthing as a solution here at [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/50de43c5-5c3e-41e4-a4fe-51500683482f/why-does-my-sharepoint-addins-id-change-every-time-i-deploy-it-from-visual-studio?forum=sharepointdevelopment)